# Autofill based on dynamic row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to start an autofill based on a dynamic range. For each column in the 'starting table' I need to stack them on top of one another. My current code starting at 'LastRow' does not do this. I was hoping LastRow would give me a dynamic Range to autofill from, but instead I get the error, 
'Object variable or With block variable not set'

**How do I change my code so that '2Move' autofills to the new size of the table, without knowing where it starts?** Then repeat the process for '3Move' and '4Move'

```
Sub shiftingColumns()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Range

Set sht = ActiveSheet

Set copyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Range("A2:B2"), Range("A2:B2").End(xlDown))
'Insert column & add header
Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("C1").Value = "Category"
'Move D1 Value to C2
Range("D1").Cut Destination:=Range("C2")
'Autofill C2 value to current table size
Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
'Copy copyRange below itself 
copyRange.Copy Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
'Move E1 below autofilled ranged
Range("E1").Cut Destination:=Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
'LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
'LastRow.AutoFill Destination:=Range(LastRow & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End Sub
```

This is the starting table

[image: Starting Table]

This is the desired table

[image: Ending table]

Comment: Please give a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's honestly pretty hard to decipher your actual question here or what you are *really* attempting.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, there is no actual question. i read it several times and did not find one.

Comment: I'll attempt to add an mcve tomorrow when I'm back at my computer. For now I've tried to clarify my question. Would it be beneficial to make a miniature table of what I'm attempting to do?

Comment: I've updated my question. Hopefully it's more clear exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @ReedRawlings It appears that you are trying to 'flatten' your table. As an alternative I would suggest to use Pivot table to do that. Otherwise you will need a loop to accomplish your task instead of `autofill`.

Comment: How would I do this in Excel 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of those finding this via search engine, what you're looking to do isn't anything like autofill.

This should work for you, a loop.

```
Sub test()

    workingSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    newSheet = "New Sheet"

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(newSheet).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Sheets.Add.Name = newSheet
    Cells(1, 1) = "ID"
    Cells(1, 2) = "Color"
    Cells(1, 3) = "Category"
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheets(workingSheet).Activate
    'Get last column
    x = Cells(1, 3).End(xlToRight).Column
    y = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    'Loop for each column from 3 (column "C") and after
    For i = 3 To x

        With Sheets(newSheet)

            newRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'Copy ID and Color
            Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(y, 2)).Copy .Range(.Cells(newRow, 1), .Cells(newRow + y, 2))
            'Copy column header
            .Range(.Cells(newRow, 3), .Cells(newRow + (y - 2), 3)) = Cells(1, i)
            'Copy column values
            Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(y, i)).Copy .Range(.Cells(newRow, 4), .Cells(newRow + y, 4))
        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

If your demands vary, such as adding other "fixed" columns like ID and Color then you'll have to change the cell addressing and such.

Comment: I'm currently working through making this work for my own sheet, but it seems great so far.

Comment: it's pretty much dynamic, the only hard-coded assumptions are the start point of column C and that the source and destination tables start in cell A1.

Comment: I have 13 columns, 9 of them are "fixed". I renamed the columns. I changed 'x = Cells(1, 10)'... and 'For i = 10 To x', but I don't know which numbers to change inside the With portion to get my desired results.

Comment: Look at the `Cells(y, 2)` and `.Cells(newRow + y, 2)` parts.  The `2` in those refer to the last column of the "fixed" range.  So you probably want to change those to `9`.

Comment: A note: you should have an error trap for `x * y > rows.count` because this will be when the data cannot expand beyond the max Excel rows.

Answer (score 2):

These two method will transpose the data much faster than `Range.Copy` and `Range.Paste`.

**PivotTableValues** - dumps the `Range.Value` into an array, data, then fills a second array, results, with the transposed values. Note: Transposed in this context simply means moved to a different place.

**PivotTableValues2** - uses Arraylists to accomplish the OP's goals.  Although it works great, it is somewhat a farcical answer.  I just wanted to try this approach for esoteric reasons.

### PivotTableValues Using Arrays

```
Sub PivotTableValues()
    Const FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT As Long = 2
    Dim ArrayRowCount As Long, Count As Long, ColumnCount As Long, RowCount As Long, x As Long, y As Long, y2 As Long
    Dim data As Variant, results As Variant, v As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        RowCount = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ColumnCount = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        data = Range(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value

        ArrayRowCount = (ColumnCount - FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT) * (RowCount - 1) + 1

        ReDim results(1 To ArrayRowCount, 1 To FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT + 2)

        Count = 1
        For y = FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT + 1 To ColumnCount
            For x = 2 To RowCount
                Count = Count + 1
                results(Count, FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT + 1) = data(1, y)
                results(Count, FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT + 2) = data(x, y)
                For y2 = 1 To FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT
                    If Count = 2 Then
                        results(1, y2) = data(1, y2)
                        results(1, y2 + 1) = "Category"
                        results(1, y2 + 2) = "Value"
                    End If
                    results(Count, y2) = data(x, y2)
                Next
            Next
        Next

    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2)).Value = results
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

### PivotTableValues2 Using ArrayLists

```
Sub PivotTableValues2()
    Const FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT As Long = 2
    Dim ColumnCount As Long, RowCount As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    Dim valueList As Object, baseList As Object, results As Variant, v As Variant
    Set valueList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set baseList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        RowCount = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ColumnCount = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For x = 1 To RowCount
            baseList.Add Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT))))
        Next

        For y = FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT + 2 To ColumnCount
            baseList.AddRange baseList.getRange(1, RowCount - 1)
        Next

        For y = FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT + 1 To ColumnCount
            For x = 2 To RowCount
                valueList.Add Array(.Cells(1, y).Value, .Cells(x, y).Value)
            Next
        Next

    End With

    results = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(baseList.ToArray))

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2)).Value = results
        valueList.Insert 0, Array("Category", "Value")

        results = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(valueList.ToArray))
        .Cells(1, FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT + 1).Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2)).Value = results
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```